# Taking too long to return results MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wamp, wampserver

I am confused why do the server is taking too much time in execution of a following query:

```
SELECT tbl1.Column1 FROM Table1 AS tbl1 
INNER JOIN Table2 AS tbl2 ON tbl2.Column4 = tbl1.Column1
```

It took about 20 minutes to return the results. MySQL config (my.ini) file looks like the following:

```
[mysql]

# CLIENT #
port                           = 3306
socket                         = X:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\data\mysql.sock

[mysqld]

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
default-storage-engine         = InnoDB
socket                         = X:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\data\mysql.sock
pid-file                       = X:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\data\mysql.pid

# MyISAM #
key-buffer-size                = 32M
myisam-recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP

# SAFETY #
max-allowed-packet             = 16M
max-connect-errors             = 1000000

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = X:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\data\

# BINARY LOGGING #
log-bin                        = X:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\data\mysql-bin
expire-logs-days               = 14
sync-binlog                    = 1

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
max-connections                = 500
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 4096
table-open-cache               = 4096

# INNODB #
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 128M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 2G

# LOGGING #
log-error                      = X:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\data\mysql-error.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes  = 1
slow-query-log                 = 1
slow-query-log-file            = X:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\data\mysql-slow.log
```

Both Tables have primary keys.

Regards,

F. Ahmed

===============
UPDATE:

After running Explain with the above query i got following results.

```
ID  SelectType  Table   Type        Key key_len     rows    extra
1   SIMPLE      tbl2    index       item_record_id  261     95361   Using index
1   SIMPLE      tbl1    index       record_id       261     88474   Using where;        Using    index; Using join buffer
```

Comment: Please, provide explain information about your query.

Comment: Most important tell us about the tables, the fields used in the join and the indexes you have on those tables. The contents of that .ini file aren't helpful. are these indexed? tbl2.Column4 and tbl1.Column1

Comment: @sectus, Explain information added

Answer (score 0):

Try these two for simple checking.

1. Please check Column4 field type and Column1 field type. If you are joining `varchar` with `INT` will take too much time return the result.
2. Use proper Indexing to speed up the query

Comment: 1 - Both columns are varchar(255)
2 - Both columns are indexed

Comment: its not a good idea to join table with varchar(255) fields, it will take too much time complete if any of the table has more than 100 records. Normalize your table or find another way to join by adding id or another field with INT type

Answer (score 0):

### EXPLAIN SELECT tbl1.Column1 FROM Table1 AS tbl1 INNER JOIN Table2 AS tbl2 ON tbl2.Column4 = tbl1.Column1;

This will help to see the number of rows reading and indexes and plenty more to see the reslut.

Comment: 1 SIMPLE tbl2 index  item_record_id 261  95361 Using index
1 SIMPLE tbl1 index  record_id 261  88474 Using where; Using index; Using join buffer

Comment: I have added the result with proper formatting in my question. Please check above.

Answer (score 0):

if the type of the 2 columns you are checking are different that can be one problem. Another problem is the server..it's not handling very well if you have millions of rows.

Comment: Table1 have about 93K rows and Table2 have about 90K rows. MySQL Configuration is already posted in the question. Any Suggestions in this regard.

Comment: try the query local..if it's taking also this long than i can't say what it's wrong...

Comment: Its not so far deployed on production, i am testing this in my local environment.